# Matching strings and storing into an array with regex in java

Tags: java, regex, split

Im making a program that takes a file and finds identifiers. So far I removed any words in quotes, any words that start with a number and I removed all the non word characters.

Is there a way to find words that dont match words in an array and store those words into another array using regex? I can figure it out, I was trying to use the split method but its not working right when I try to split by spaces...This is what I did to split it.

```
String[] SplitString = newLine.split("[\\s]");
```

Comment: please give an example..

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String[] SplitString = newLine.split("\\s");
```

if you don't want to combine multiple spaces/tabs, etc., but use

```
String[] SplitString = newLine.split("\\s+");
```

if you do. For example, if your string is:

```
"a  b c"
```

the first will give you four tokens: `"a"`, `""`, `"b"`, and `"c"`, and the second will give you three: `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply in one line by first removing the known words, then splitting:

```
String[] unknownWords = newLine.replaceAll("\\b(apple|orange|banana)\\b", "").split("\\s+");
```

Notes:

- Your regex `[\s]` is equivalent to `\s`, so I simplified it
- You should probably split on *any number* of spaces: `\s+`
- `\b` means "word boundary" - this means the removal regex *won't* match `applejack`
- The regex `(A|B|C|etc)` is the syntax for "OR" logic